# How to add a dynamic favicon in a nextjs app on a dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, favicon

I want my nextjs app to have a different favicon based on the route.
[This](https://world-ranklist.vercel.app/) is the working application where I want to implement this. I want the favicon to become the countries flag whenever someone goes to that countries page.

I have the following code in my react components Head tag:

```js
            <Head>
                <title>{country.name} | {country.subregion}</title>
                <link rel="icon" href={country.flag} />
            </Head>
```

This works sometimes but most of the times the favicon is not updated or the previous favicon stays.

Answer (score 4):

One issue that I had was that your `<link>` element must be a direct child of next.js's `<Head>` element. This means you cannot have a `<Favicon>` React element that internally renders a `<link>` element. Instead you should call your `<Favicon {...props}>` React element as a function as shown below:

```
<Head>
  {Favicon({...props})}
</Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me.
Thats my solution.
In href, navigate to file folder.

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../file.svg" />
      </Head>

      <div>Something...</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is catching the pathname on the client side in a favicon component that just swaps the favicon src based on the route. what you would end up with would be kind like the following:

app:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Favicons from "../components/favicons";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <Favicons currentRoute={router.pathname} />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />   
    </>
  );
};
```

and then in the favicons component something like this:

```js
const Favicons = (currentRoute) => {
  switch (currentRoute) {
    case "variant-1":
      return (
        <>
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="180x180"
            href="/favicons/[version]/apple-touch-icon.png"
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="32x32"
            href="/favicons/[version]/favicon-32x32.png"
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="16x16"
            href="/favicons/[version]/favicon-16x16.png"
          />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/favicons/[version]/site.webmanifest" />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/[version]/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#603cba" />
          <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicons/[version]/browserconfig.xml" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
        </>
      );
    case "variant-2":
      return (
        <>
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="180x180"
            href="/favicons/[version]/apple-touch-icon.png"
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="32x32"
            href="/favicons/[version]/favicon-32x32.png"
          />
          <link
            rel="icon"
            type="image/png"
            sizes="16x16"
            href="/favicons/[version]/favicon-16x16.png"
          />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/favicons/[version]/site.webmanifest" />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/[version]/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#603cba" />
          <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicons/[version]/browserconfig.xml" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
        </>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <>
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/favicons/site.webmanifest" />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#603cba" />
          <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicons/browserconfig.xml" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
        </>
      );
  }
};
export default Favicons;
```

Then again, no clue if ya still got relatable issues but hope this helps ya!